# Azure extension error while calling PowerShell script

Tags: json, azure, powershell

Using PowerShell, I am trying to encode text file to a string and encoded string is provided as input to get cook book name and recipe details. When I check the output cookbook name and Json file, they are string and valid json file. But when I use this code via Azure extension, I get error -
message:

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Unterminated string passed in.
FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

```
#Encode the Input file
[string]$sStringToEncode=Get-Content "c:\temp\json.txt"
$sEncodedString=[Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($sStringToEncode))
write-host -ForegroundColor Green "Encoded String:`n" $sEncodedString

#Decode text
$EncodedText = $sEncodedString.replace("\n","")
write-host "String after replacing \n:" $EncodedText
$DecodedText = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($EncodedText))

#Convert to Json file
$DecodedText | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File c:\temp\DNAFiledata.json

#Taking out cookbook Name
$CookbookName = (Get-Content c:\temp\DNAFiledata.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json).cookbook_name
$CookbookName | Out-File "c:\temp\3_CookBookName.txt"

#Taking out recipe details
$Datainput = (Get-Content -Raw -Path c:\temp\DNAFiledata.json | ConvertFrom-Json).chef_attributes | ConvertTo-Json
$Datainput | Out-File "c:\temp\4_Datainput.json"

$Datainput | Set-Content "c:\temp\$CookbookName.json"
```

Any suggestions on this please.

Comment: Show the contents of `c:\temp\json.txt`. Chances are this is already a valid JSON and you are corrupting it by encoding/decoding..

Comment: Appreciate your help on this.
Content of json.txt -->
{
"cookbook_name":"test-cb-compliance",
"chef_attributes":{
"test-cb-mcafee":{"install_ens":true},
"test-cb-security-compliance":{"highsecure":true},
"test-cb-pkgrepo":{"force":true},
"run_list":["recipe[test-cb-compliance]"
]
}
}
Please excuse indentation.
Encoded string comes as input for ps1 script via automation. From "#Decode text" section, script decodes the content and apply the cookbooks and recipe's on the windows server. It runs fine within server but fails while calling from Azure Api's.

Comment: I still don't see why you want to base64 encode and next decode again.. However, I think you are missing the `-Raw` switch in the very first line, meaning you'll get an **array** of lines from the text file. Change that to `[string]$sStringToEncode=Get-Content "c:\temp\json.txt" -Raw`. As aside: $EncodedText should not have newlines in it, but if you insist, remove with  `$sEncodedString -replace '\r?\n'`

Comment: base64 encoding is performed on automation server and encoded string is passed on as input to PowerShell script. 
Let me try with these suggestions. 
Appreciate your help!!!